# All the pictures from the gallery in a view -- Android

Tags: android, image, gallery

How can I make that all the pictures from my gallery appear in one view in Android Studio? I need all of my pictures to use after face recognition on them.

Here is the begining of my code:

```
    package com.face.user.faceapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

//import static android.widget.ImageView.*;


public class FirstClass extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    // private ImageView image;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        //  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;

    @Override
    //semmi
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

    }
}
```

and the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Click here" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but if I run this I can just pick one photo from my gallery and I need all of them in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `putExtra` on intent like this:

```
//  ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

N.B. *Works in API 18 and higher.*